# Как убрать лишние слова?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть команда, которая показывает топ онлайна по голосовому онлайну
Я бы хотел чтобы она не показывала те значение где фигурирует "0"
То есть, если у участника онлайн 0h 9m 0s, то покажет только его 9m

```
const Command = require('../../structures/Command.js');
const MemberModel = require('../../models/Member.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

class Top extends Command {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }

    async run(message) {
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        let guild = message.guild,
            ranks = await MemberModel
                .find({ guildId: guild.id })
                .sort({ voiceTime: 'desc' })
                .limit(10),
            i = 1;
        
        ranks.forEach(rank => {
            let voiceonline = rank.voiceTime;
            let member = guild.members.cache.get(rank.fullId.split('-')[1]);
            function convertSecondsToTime(usePad = false) {
                let seconds = voiceonline
                let minutes = Math.floor(voiceonline / 60)
                let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60)
                seconds = seconds % 60
                minutes = minutes % 60
                const pad = num => {
                  const n = num.toString()
                  return n > 9 ? '' + n : '' + n
                }
                return {
                  h: (usePad) ? pad(hours) : hours,
                  m: (usePad) ? pad(minutes) : minutes,
                  s: (usePad) ? pad(seconds) : seconds,
                }
              }
            let timev = convertSecondsToTime(voiceonline)
      if (member) {
          embed.addField(`#${i++} — ${member.user.tag}`, `**${timev.h}**h **${timev.m}**m **${timev.s}**s`);
      }
    })
        embed.setTitle("ТОП-10 голосового онлайна")
        embed.setColor("#36393f");
        embed.setFooter(`Выполнил(а) ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic : true}));
        embed.setTimestamp();
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}

module.exports = Top;
```

Comment: ну и добавьте  проверку `tivev.h < 0 ? timev.h : ''` и тд, либо replace

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, так, чтобы не менять функцию. Воспользуемся тем, что имя ключей совпадает с припиской к числу, и тем, что алфавитный порядок ключей совпадает с порядком вывода:

```js
            let timev = Object.entries(convertSecondsToTime(voiceonline))
                          .filter(([key, value]) => Number(value) !== 0)
                          .map(([key, value]) => `**${value}${key}**`)
                          .join(' ');
      if (member) {
          embed.addField(`#${i++} — ${member.user.tag}`, timev);
      }
```